# Category of schemes with flat morphisms

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, commutative-algebra

Consider the category whose objects are schemes, and for every two schemes $X$ and $Y$, morphisms $\operatorname{Hom}(X,Y)$ consist of *flat* morphisms $X\rightarrow Y$, only. Does this category have a name in the literature?